Is a splitting subfield of a splitting field generated by a subgroup of automorphisms?
Let $m_x$ denote the minimal polynomial of the element $x$, and $\sqrt[\mathrm{R}]{p}$ the set of roots of the polynomial $p$. Let $p\in F[x]$ be an irreducible polynomial over a zero-characteristic field $F$. Also, let $\Sigma_p$ and $G_p$ be the splitting field and galois group of $p$, respectively. I'm investigating wether is it the case that, if $\alpha\in\Sigma_p$, then $\frac{m_\alpha}{F}=\Sigma_\alpha$ (the splitting field of $m_\alpha$) shows:
$$\Sigma_\alpha=F\left(\bigcup_{\sigma\in H}\{\sigma(\alpha)\}\right)$$
For some $H≤ G_p$ (using the field generated by a subset notation).
I attempted to do the following:
Let $f\in \Sigma_p[x]$ be defined as
$$f(x)=\prod_{\sigma\in G_p}(x-\sigma(\alpha))$$
Since $e\in G_p$ (the identity element) we know that $(x-\alpha)|f$. With a little work, we can show that $f\in F[x]$, and hence (since $m_\alpha$ is minimal), we have the following ideal inclusions:
$$⟨f⟩\subseteq⟨m_\alpha⟩\subseteq F[x]\subseteq\Sigma_p[x]$$
Particularly, it can be easily observed that $\sqrt[\mathrm{R}]{m_\alpha}\subseteq\sqrt[\mathrm{R}]{f}$, so
$$m_\alpha(x)=\prod_{\sigma\in H}(x-\sigma(\alpha))$$
For some $H\subseteq G_p$.
The previous equation shows that
$$\sqrt[\mathrm{R}]{m_\alpha}=\bigcup_{\sigma\in H}\{\sigma(\alpha)\}$$
And hence
$$\Sigma_\alpha=F(\sqrt[\mathrm{R}]{m_\alpha})=F\left(\bigcup_{\sigma\in H}\{\sigma(\alpha)\}\right)$$
For some subset $H$ of $G_p$. It remains to be shown that $H$ is a group: it obviously contains the identity element, but i'm struggling to show the closure and inverse axioms.

The notation $m_\alpha/$ in the 4th sentence makes no sense. Please give an actual example describing what you are asking about.

@KCd ,it is a common notation in the literature. $\frac{p}{F}$ stands for "the splitting field of $p$ over $F$". An example would be: $F=\mathbb{Q}$, $p=x^4-2$, $\alpha=i\in\Sigma_p=\mathbb{Q}(i,\sqrt[4]{2})$. Then, $\frac{m_\alpha}{F}=\mathbb{Q}(i)$.

What is such literature?  I have never seen $\frac{p}{}$ in any abstract algebra book.

@KCd is it that important? I did clarify, ever since the OP, that $\frac{m_\alpha}{F}$ meant the splitting field of the minimal polynomial $m_\alpha$ of $\alpha$ over $F$, which is pretty standard terminology.

Sure it is not important, but I have never seen such notation before and am surprised to see it called "common".  I would like to learn what book uses it.

The question is asking whether an element $\alpha$ in a Galois extension $E/F$ has its splitting field over $F$ equal to $F(\{\sigma(\alpha) : \sigma \in H\})$ where $H$ is a subgroup of $G = {\rm Gal}(E/F)$.  The answer is yes: just use $H = G$. That is, apply $G$ to $\alpha$ and adjoin all the results to $F$. That extension of $F$ is the splitting field of $\alpha$ over $F$.  This is actually a standard result in Galois theory: the splitting field of $\alpha$ over $F$ has to contain each $\sigma(\alpha)$ where $\sigma$ runs over $G$, and conversely $F(\{\sigma(\alpha) : \sigma \in H\})$ is Galois of $F$ since it is separable and normal.
In practice there will be many repetitions in the list $\{\sigma(\alpha) : \sigma \in G\}$, but there is no rule that a list of field generators can't have repetitions. In case you want no repetitions, then just replace that list by the distinct elements in the list.  It is not reasonable to expect the list of distinct $\sigma(\alpha)$ to be indexed by $\sigma$ running over a subgroup of $G$. Instead, it is indexed by the cosets of a subgroup: let $H := \{\sigma \in G : \sigma(\alpha) = \alpha\}$, which is a subgroup of $G$. Then the distinct elements in $\{\sigma(\alpha) : \sigma \in G\}$ can be described as $\{\sigma(\alpha) : \sigma \in G/H\}$ since all elements in a left coset of $G/H$ have the same effect on $\alpha$.
